# Which kubernetes mode to chose

Tags: kubernetes

I have a situation where each message in a message queue has to be processed by a separate instance (one pod can process one message at a time). Many messages can be processed at once, but there is a limit of parallel executions. Once it's reached, no new messages are being pulled from the queue. Message processing takes about 30 minutes. No state needs to be stored on the pods between calls (all data is read from a database when pod starts processing a message). A new message should spawn a new pod, once the processing finishes, the pod should die.

Should I use Deployments, ReplicaSets, StatefulSets, Services? (we use Kubernetes with Azure) I guess the main

I've tried ReplicaSets, but in a situation when three messages are being processed and one finishes, scaling down a ReplicaSet can kill a working pod, which is definately not what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that since you do not need to handle state you must discard the StatefulSets, on the other hand, a Deployment is a higher-level concept of ReplicaSets, so, you should use a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) as it takes care of the replica set. Lastly, as your processing is under demand I would consider using [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#running-an-example-job), once the job completes the task it frees the resources and dies, this would require extra code to create the jobs based on a helper but could be very handy.